# Prove that a sequence has a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing

Sequence $a_{n}$ satisfies $|a_{n}| \leq n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let sequence $b_{n} = \frac{a_{n} + 5}{n^{2} + a_{n}}$, prove that $b_{n}$ has a limit, and find it.

I know that $b_{n}$ has a limit $b$, then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $n \geq N$ implies $|b_{n} - b| < \epsilon$. 
I know that $b_{n}$ will approach 0 as $n$ increases because $|a_{n}| \leq n$. So in that case I would have

$|0 - b| < \epsilon \Rightarrow b < \epsilon$

And then I'm not sure what to do after that

Comment: If you think that 0 is the limit, then you need to prove that, given $\varepsilon >0$, exists $N$ such that $n>N \implies |b_n -0| <\varepsilon$. Work from the last inequality and "solve it" for $n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**
$$|b_n|\le \frac{|a_n|+5}{|n^2+a_n|}\le \frac{n+5}{|n^2+a_n|}\le \frac{n+5}{|n^2|-|a_n|}$$

*edit*. As I see the question at first, the term $a_n$ in denominator is $a_2$ so I edit my answer. Last inequality is achieved by using reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: $$|b_n|\le \frac{|a_{n}|+5}{|n^2+a_{n}|}\le \frac{n+5}{|n^2+a_{n}|} \leq \frac{n}{n^2} < \epsilon \Rightarrow n > \frac{1}{\epsilon} $$ Does this seem right?

Comment: @Adrian I edit my answer. Please refer my modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's divide everything by $n$ and remember that the limit of ratio equal to ratio of limits, i.e.

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\frac{a_n}{n} + \frac{5}{n}}{n + \frac{a_2}{n}} = \frac{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{a_n}{n} + \frac{5}{n}\right)}{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(n + \frac{a_2}{n}\right)} \leq \frac{1 + 0}{+\infty + 0} = 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove that $b_n$ tends to zero. To do this, you want to prove that it isn't too big. So here is a hint.

Prove that for all $n \geq 2$, we have $|b_n| \leq \frac{n+5}{n^2 - 2} \leq \frac{8}{n}$.